# Does cache-control:private without expiration data imply "expire immediately"?

Tags: asp.net, caching, standards, cache-control

Most content I've observed being served from ASP.NET has only a Cache-Control: private header, with no Last-Modified or Etag header.

I've also observed that browsers *never* seem to cache this content, evidenced by having never seen browsers issue anything but unconditional GET requests for it.

I'm trying to support the assertion that a resource having Cache-Control:private and no expiration data will be treated by all browsers as "do not cache", but can't find anything in the RFC (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to confirm or refute it.

Is my assertion correct?  Please cite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an email chain over on W3C which dates back about 15 years: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-private.html

> (1) "Cache-control: private" remains as in Roy's draft, but with a
>   mention of extensibility explicitly included. Single-user-agent caches
>   are effectively allowed to ignore this directive.
>
> (2) "Cache-control: no-cache" is defined to mean exactly the same
>   thing as "Cache-control: private", but with no exception for
>   user-agent caches.
>
> (3) We add "Cache-control: no-store", which applies to the entire
>   message and may be sent either in a response or in a request. If sent
>   in a request, it means "do not store any part of either this request
>   or any response to it."  If sent in a response, it means "do not store
>   any part of either this response or the request that elicited it."
>   This applies to both single-user and shared caches.  Caches should
>   obey it but we explicitly caution against depending on it as a privacy
>   mechanism.  Users may explicitly store such responses outside of the
>   caching system (e.g., with a "Save as" dialog. History buffers may
>   store such responses as part of their normal operation.

It goes on to say:

> The "private" directive indicates that parts of the response message
>   are intended for a single user and must not be cached except within a
>   private (non-shared) cache controlled by the user agent.

And most importantly:

> Anyway, it seems like the main difference between "private" and
>   "no-cache" is that "private" allows caching in a user agent's
>   single-user cache, whereas "no-cache" does not.

So on this basis I'm taking it to mean that non-private caching is disallowed (i.e. at the proxy layer), but private caching *is* allowed (i.e. within the browser). I know this is simply discussion about a draft spec but it's the best explanation I've been able to find so far.